# Make image be identified as being linked in visio

Tags: visio

I have made it so that when I double click on certain images in Visio, it will take you to another page.  Is there a way that the image can be identified as being linked so that if i sent it to someone, they would know to click on it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the appearance of the shape can to a lot to suggest the shape is a link. See the "Off-page connector" shape

Also take a look at how the "Off-page reference" shape is implemented. It uses a Hyperlink in addition to the double click event. This causes the pointer change when you mouse over the shape.

Unfortunately both approaches suggest that the shape links somewhere but don't tell you have to **double click** to follow the link.